# There was an error when executing the ghc-modi `type` command:

Tags: haskell

I try to use the data.maybe type but failed. When I tried to run it in ghci, it told me"The constructor ‘Ramen’ should have no arguments, but has been given 1.". How can I fix it?

```
data Product = Ramen | Chips

totalPrice :: Product -> Integer -> Float

totalPrice product = case product of
                Ramen x
                     | x >= 200 -> 1.35*x
                     | x <= 200 -> 1.4*x
                     | x <= 100 -> 1.5*x
                     | x <= 30 -> 1.8*x
                     | x <= 10 -> 2.0*x
                     | otherwise -> error "Something's wrong."
                Chips x
                     | x >= 21 -> 2.35*x
                     | x <= 20 -> 2.5*x
                     | x <= 10 -> 2.7*x
                     | x <= 5 -> 2.95*x
                     | x >= 1 && x <= 2 -> 3.0*x
                     |otherwise -> error "Something's wrong."
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in exactly what compiler says:

```
The constructor ‘Ramen’ should have no arguments, but has been given 1.
```

`Ramen` and `Chips` have definition `data Product = Ramen | Chips`, but receive an argument in `case` expression (`Ramen x` and `Chips x`). In order to fix the compile error, you'll need:

Either change `Ramen x` and `Chips x` to just `Ramen` and `Chips` and move `x` into the function definition or change you data constructors to `data Product = Ramen Integer | Chips Integer` and move `Integer` out of `totalPrice :: Product -> Integer -> Float`. Probably, the first option is more suitable.

But after fixing this problem you'll get another one:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’ with actual type ‘Integer’
```

It can be fixed by using `fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b`.

This should fix the compile errors, but after calling the `totalPrice Ramen 10` you'll get `14.0` as a result, but I assume you're expecting `20.0`. That's because `case` fails on `x >= 200 -> 1.35*x`, but succeeds on `x <= 200 -> 1.4*x`.

The following example will compile and return:

```
200 * 1.35 on totalPrice Ramen 200
150 * 1.4 on totalPrice Ramen 150
and
10 * 2.0 on totalPrice Ramen 10
```

But, I think it's not encouraged to use `error` in `Haskell`, what about just returning `0` is `count` is negative?

```
totalPrice :: Product -> Integer -> Float    
totalPrice product count = case product of
                Ramen
                     | x >= 200 -> 1.35*x
                     | x >  100 -> 1.4*x
                     | x >  30 -> 1.5*x
                     | x >  10 -> 1.8*x
                     | x >= 0 -> 2.0*x
                     | otherwise -> 0
                Chips
                     | x >= 21 -> 2.35*x
                     | x >  10 -> 2.5*x
                     | x >  5 -> 2.7*x
                     | x >  2 -> 2.95*x
                     | x >= 0 -> 3.0*x
                     | otherwise -> 0
   where x = fromIntegral count
```

Comment: Great answer! Worked for me.Thanks for your advice.